# Ubuntu bug? Environment variables only after logging as root

Tags: linux, bash, variables, ubuntu, environment

I have an IP address that I use very often, so I tried to set it as an environment variable now that I installed Ubuntu. I edited /etc/environment and added a couple of lines for my api token and my IP address. It looks like this:

```
PATH="some/paths"
TOKEN="my:token"
ZRUS="my.ip.address"
```

Now if I want to access the IP I would in theory do `ssh $ZRUS`. However, it does not work; I do `echo $ZRUS` and I get a blank line, so I do `printenv` and I get a list of all the environment variables and I don't see my IP there. I then do `su root` and I do `printenv` again and I get the same list plus the IP address and the TOKEN. I then do `su myuser` and do `echo $ZRUS` and magically the IP works.

Now I'm wondering why I have to log in as root first to get my global environment variables to work in the local user. It seems as if the scope varied depending on whether root has had a go on the session or not, which seems strange to me.

Do you guys think this is a bug or a functionality? And how would you overcome this?

Comment: I guess the variables are not expanded by the `shell`. You specifically want to add them in `/etc/environment` or use `/etc/profile` which is sourced every time a new `shell` is created.

Comment: You might consider adding a new entry to `/etc/hosts` or your `.ssh/config` file instead of defining an environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables set in an environment file `/etc/environment` will only take effect if you read them into your active shell `source /etc/environment` or you logout/login (which will re-read the environment files into your active shell).

The act of `su myuser` is essentially creating a new shell for your current user which re-reads the environment file

Comment: oh, this makes sense, I'll retry tomorrow after I turn on my computer again. Thanks!